# Mysql INSERT data in Table 2 for each row in Table 1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table A is a list of questions that needs to be filtered by question type.
e.g. SELECT * from TableA WHERE Qtype = "whatever"

I then need to add four new records to Table B for each record pulled by the query on TableA.

Table A and Table B join on an ID number - TableA.id = TableB.questionid

I am presuming I will need to run it four times, once for each record that I add.

I am getting confused on the FOR EACH command in conjunction with an INNER JOIN

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: What data do you want in `TableB`?

Comment: TableB needs new data in it.  So for each record pulled from Table 1, a new record would be inserted in Table 2 that has the id number from table 1 and then some next text in another column.  e.g. Table1 record reads id, 1   qtype, whatever  and then Table2 new record would read questionid, 1 (being pulled from table1.id)  newfield, "excellent"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576293/mysql-triggers-insert-into-another-table

Answer (score 3):

Try this 4 times :

```
INSERT INTO TableB (questionid, otherfieldB)
VALUES (
    SELECT id, otherfieldA
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Qtype = "whatever"
)
```

Comment: So close but the otherfieldB is to be filled with new data that does not exist in TableA.

Comment: why not INSERT INTO TableB (questionid, otherfieldB)

    SELECT id, otherfieldA, "CustomValue"
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Qtype = "whatever"

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I still don't fully understand your question, but this will insert three records into `TableB` for each record of `TableA`, with three different values for `newfield`:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID, newfield) (
  SELECT a.ID, n.newfield
  FROM (
    SELECT 'Excellent' AS newfield UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Something else'
  ) n
  CROSS JOIN TableA a
)
```