# Triggers on MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Helllo, I have the following table `Scores`:

```
ID
Name
Value
Creation_date
Modification_date
```

I also have table `Scores_History`:

```
ID
Name
Value
Creation_date
```

What I need to do is to set a trigger, so when a row in table `Scores` is updated, it will store the old `Name` and `Value` inside the `Scores_History` table (create a new row).

Can someone help me to figure out the query, since nothing I tried is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, assuming the id column in scores_history is auto_increment:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER scores_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON scores
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO scores_history (name, value, creation_date)
   VALUES (OLD.name, OLD.value, OLD.creation_date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Actually, you probably want the `"creation_date"` column to contain the current date and time, rather than the value from the `scores` table.

To get that behavior, modify the trigger to replace the reference to `"OLD.creation_date"` with a reference to `"NOW()"`.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `Scores`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `Scores_History` (Name, Value, Creation_date) VALUES(OLD.Name, OLD.Value, OLD.Creation_date);
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Similar: [MySQL Triggers insert into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576293/mysql-triggers-insert-into-another-table?rq=1)