# using mysql how to insert rows in audit table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I am new to mysql,
I have two table employee and audit

1. employee Table have 4 columns

   1. id
   2. name
   3. sal
   4. role
2. audit Table have 7 columns

   1. id
   2. type
   3. old_value
   4. new_value
   5. date
   6. username

Here , I want to insert 3 rows in audit table if someone add one row in employee table. To maintain the history

for eg: I made an entry in employee table

```
John | 20,000 | anaylst
```

Than my audit table will be

```
Type  | old_value |new_value | date        | username  
  name|           |John      | 01/04/2015  | dummy1
   sal|           |20,000    | 01/04/2015  | dummy1
 role |           |anaylst   | 01/04/2015  | dummy1
```

I am unable to insert rows in audit table.

Comment: if you want to include a username in that (i assume not the mysql username, but someone logged into a website) you're going to have to do it out in script / php land

Comment: leave username part for a moment I can able to do that . More concern , how to instert 3 row in audit table

Comment: @pala_ perhaps the `CURRENT_USER()` function could be used? http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/current_user.php

Comment: @pala_perhaps ... yes I am using the same .

Comment: @Turophile sure, in the unlikely event that it's the actual mysql user that he's wanting to capture. I'm assuming its the username of someone accessing a web application, which would be using a generic account to access the db.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

See this answer for details: [MySQL Triggers insert into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576293/mysql-triggers-insert-into-another-table)